# Cannot get kube-dns and weave-net running in kubernetes

Tags: dns, installation, kubernetes, ubuntu-16.04, vmware-player

I'm trying to do a fresh installation of kubernetes in my local system for which I have installed Ubuntu Server 16.04 on VM Player with two instances as nodes and one as master. The problem is I'm stuck at step 4 of the link pasted below for installation. The services `kube-dns` and `weave-net` won't start. Can anybody help me?

[image]

Link used for installation: https://lukemarsden.github.io/docs/getting-started-guides/kubeadm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That document is old one. use the latest one from here. https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/

I would recommend to follow this workshop steps. this is more recent one.

https://github.com/luxas/kubeadm-workshop